# ReactJS: How do i pass variable to another function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

All i intend to do is to pass the variable(`list`)defined inside map method to a another function, so as to make that value default after edit click event, i was able to do it through `ref` (not through value property but through innerText, need to know why ?), however, after clicking on save button it throws an error message `innerText is not defined` here is my code:

PARENT:

```
export default class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       todoArr: [],
    }

   this.editTo = this.editTo.bind(this);
  }

editTo(text, i) {
   var lists = this.state.todoArr;
   lists[i] = text;
   this.setState({todoArr: lists})
 }
render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <form>
        <Children {...this.state} EditTodos={this.editTo}/>
       </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

CHILDREN:

```
export default class Children extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      editing: false,
    };
  }


handleSave(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.EditTodos(this.refs.textVal.innerText, i)
  }

  render_Display() {
    return(
      <div>
       {
        this.props.listArr.map((list,i) => {
           return(
             <div key={i} index={i} ref="textVal" id="_list">
              <li>{list}</li>
             </div>
           )})
       }
       </div>
    );
  }
  render_Form() {
   return(
      <div>
        <textarea defaultValue={this.refs.textVal.innerText}/> //this.refs.textVal.value is not working
        <button onClick={(e) => this.handleSave(e)} 
         className="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk" 
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
```

I'm not sure how i would pass `i` to handleSave in order to save the right index todo, Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show where is your edit button and how you are rendering `render_Form` ?

Comment: You are giving the same name as `ref` for all the list items.